# Serverless offline and DynamoDB local on docker

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-dynamodb, serverless-framework, serverless-offline

I want to train on Serverless with a DynamoDB local docker.
However, with this code I get an empty list of tables :

```
import { DynamoDB, Endpoint } from "aws-sdk";

export const handler = async (event, context, cb) => {
   const ddb = new DynamoDB();

   if (process.env["DYNAMO_LOCAL_ENDPT"]) {
     ddb.endpoint = new Endpoint(process.env["DYNAMO_LOCAL_ENDPT"]);
    // the local env variable = http://localhost:8000
   }

   const tables = await ddb.listTables().promise();

  const response = {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify({
    message: "Hello World!",
    tables,
    }),
  };
  return response;
};
```

But if I do the same using AWS CLI on Powershell with the command,

```
aws dynamodb list-tables --endpoint-url http://localhost:8000
```

I get the right response with my 2 tables on my docker.

Can you tell me what's wrong with my code ?

Comment: I think that when you test in docker, `http://localhost:8000` will refer to localhost in the docker, not your host. When  you use aws cli, you are using localhost in your host operating system, not in the docker container.

Comment: I don't use the docker CLI but the AWS CLI on powershell

Comment: So how do you run your lambda code? Also, have you verified that the regions are same when you use AWS CLI and when you run your function?

Comment: I run it with serverless-offline plugin

Answer (score 0):

The DynamoDB docker region is the same that the one configured in your AWS CLI.

The region in your Serverless Yaml has to be the same (by default it's us-east-1) even if you work locally.